# OpenGL ES 2.0 Measure Performance (FPS) (Frame Duration)

Tags: java, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

When I was reading up on measuring Frames Per Second in OpenGL I came across this:

[How to measure true FPS performance of OpenGL ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586635/how-to-measure-true-fps-performance-of-opengl-es)

What I got from it was that you can get the FPS but its not a true indication of performance, and that Frame Duration would be a better choice. Are their any other ways to measure rendering performances for OpenGL? And if so why are they better (or worse) than the last?

I'm not sure I understood why FPS is not a good indication for performance too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much that it's not a 'true indication of performance', it's just that if you don't know what you're talking about it can be easily misleading.

If you really want to target a certain FPS, then there's nothing wrong with looking at it as a metric, but you just have to remember that it's not a linear measure of performance.

For example, if your FPS goes from 30 to 20, then that's a pretty significant decrease in frame performance time (33 ms to 50 ms)

However if your FPS goes from 2000 to 400, that's a miniscule difference in real time (only 2ms difference).

Using FPS is discouraged because then you get new developers worked up in a panic saying *"my FPS decreased by 1600, what did I do wrong??"*

Comment: Thanks for the response again, appreciate it!