# Getting the frame rate of a GPUImageView

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I have a GPUImageView which a stack of GPUImageFilters targets to, with a GPUImageVideoCamera at the base. How can I get the frame rate of that specific view for performance testing. I don't want the frame rate of the entire window stack, just the GPUImageView.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found so far: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6587465/2137369